# error installing glove-python : 'cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Tags: windows-10, cython, python-3.5

I am trying to install glove-python package on python3.5 (x64) and I got errors as it is shown below.

Note that I have TDM-GCC-64, MinGW32,  MinGW64  ,Cygwin, microsot visual c++ for python 2.7 , microsoft visual 2008 (x64) and  microsoft visual c++ 2015 (x64) Redistributable installed on my windows 10 to try to solve the problem.

I tried many solutions like creating distutils.cfg file to build package using mingw32/cygwin/mingw64 but all my trials gave me different errors! so I deleted the distutils.cfg file at all , But also this gives me an error as it is shown below .

Note: the path written in the error is for microsoft visual c++ for python 2.7 (but I am using python35) so this may be the cause of the error ?

Also I feel that the error may be due to Cython not running . I installed Cython 0.25.2 using pip install .But when I run pycharm debugger it gives me a warning that debugger speedups using cython not found.Also I got errors (during my trials to install the package by different ways) when building "glove.glove_cython".

Here is the error :

```
C:\Users\ESCA>pip3 install glove-python
Collecting glove-python
Using cached glove_python-0.1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from glove-python)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from glove-python)
Building wheels for collected packages: glove-python
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for glove-python ... error
Complete output from command c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ESCA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-4tm726dc\\glove-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\ESCA\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0war2fdwpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\glove
copying glove\corpus.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\glove
copying glove\glove.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\glove
copying glove\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\glove
running build_ext
building 'glove.glove_cython' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove
C:\Users\ESCA\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include -Ic:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include /Tcglove/glove_cython.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove/glove_cython.obj -fopenmp -ffast-math -march=native
 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-ffast-math'
 cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-march=native'
 glove_cython.c
 c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include\pyconfig.h(68) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Users\\ESCA\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for glove-python
Running setup.py clean for glove-python
Complete output from command c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ESCA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-4tm726dc\\glove-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
 or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
 or: -c --help-commands
 or: -c cmd --help

error: option --all not recognized

----------------------------------------
Failed cleaning build dir for glove-python
Failed to build glove-python
Installing collected packages: glove-python
Running setup.py install for glove-python ... error
Complete output from command c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ESCA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-4tm726dc\\glove-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ESCA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-gs05_i6s-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'glove.glove_cython' extension
C:\Users\ESCA\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include -Ic:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include /Tcglove/glove_cython.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\glove/glove_cython.obj -fopenmp -ffast-math -march=native
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-ffast-math'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-march=native'
glove_cython.c
c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\include\pyconfig.h(68) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Users\\ESCA\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\esca\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ESCA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-4tm726dc\\glove-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ESCA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-gs05_i6s-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ESCA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4tm726dc\glove-python\
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this `setup.py` instead when you're compiling, works on the default install directories in Windows x64 machines:

```
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np
import os

try:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools import Extension
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension

module = 'mymodule'

ext_modules = [Extension(module, sources=[module + '.pyx'],
              include_dirs=['C://Program Files (x86)//Windows Kits//10//Include//10.0.10240.0//ucrt','C://Program Files (x86)//Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0//VC//include','C://Program Files (x86)//Windows Kits//8.1//Include//shared'],
              library_dirs=['C://Program Files (x86)//Windows Kits//8.1//bin//x64', 'C://Windows//System32', 'C://Program Files (x86)//Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0//VC//lib//amd64', 'C://Program Files (x86)//Windows Kits//8.1//Lib//winv6.3//um//x64', 'C://Program Files (x86)//Windows Kits//10//Lib//10.0.10240.0//ucrt//x64'], 
              extra_compile_args=['/Ot', '/favor:INTEL64', '/EHsc', '/GA', '/openmp'],
              language='c++')]

setup(
    name = module,
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    include_dirs = [np.get_include(), os.path.join(np.get_include(), 'numpy')]
    )
```

Note the above may need some serious editing for your paths to each include directory, as well as for the package you're installing.  You're better off with Python 3.5 on Windows x64 to install Visual Studio 2015 Community then doing the `python setup.py install` from a VS command prompt that sets up all the include directories for you, either the `VS2015 x64 native tools` or `MSBuild command prompt for VS2015` which appear after installing Community.  Note that the VS2015 versions require Community at least to build Python modules as they got rid of the prior ability to compile via Microsoft redistributables.